# OpenBSD 6.1 termio.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c, autotools, automake, bsd

I try to build my code with OpenBSD 6.1 but I get this error message.

```
sh.h:98:20: error: termio.h: No such file or directory
In file included from edit.c:1:
sh.h:235: error: conflicting types for 'rlim_t'
/usr/include/sys/types.h:145: error: previous declaration of 'rlim_t' was here
In file included from edit.c:1:
sh.h:2291: warning: 'struct termio' declared inside parameter list
sh.h:2291: warning: its scope is only this definition or declaration, which is probably not what you want
edit.c: In function 'x_mode':
edit.c:3256: error: invalid use of undefined type 'struct termio'
edit.c:3256: error: 'VERASE' undeclared (first use in this function)
edit.c:3256: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
edit.c:3256: error: for each function it appears in.)
edit.c:3256: error: invalid use of undefined type 'struct termio'
edit.c:3257: error: invalid use of undefined type 'struct termio'
edit.c:3257: error: 'VKILL' undeclared (first use in this function)
edit.c:3257: error: invalid use of undefined type 'struct termio'
edit.c:3258: error: invalid use of undefined type 'struct termio'
edit.c:3258: error: 'VINTR' undeclared (first use in this function)
edit.c:3258: error: invalid use of undefined type 'struct termio'
edit.c:3259: error: invalid use of undefined type 'struct termio'
edit.c:3259: error: 'VQUIT' undeclared (first use in this function)
edit.c:3259: error: invalid use of undefined type 'struct termio'
edit.c:3260: error: invalid use of undefined type 'struct termio'
edit.c:3260: error: 'VEOF' undeclared (first use in this function)
edit.c:3260: error: invalid use of undefined type 'struct termio'
edit.c:3293: error: 'TCSETAW' undeclared (first use in this function)
*** Error 1 in src (Makefile:774 'edit.o')
*** Error 1 in . (Makefile:834 'all-recursive')
*** Error 1 in /root/opsh (Makefile:750 'all')
# pkg_add termios
quirks-2.304 signed on 2017-04-02T15:01:33Z
Can't find termios
# pkg_add termios 
# termios
ksh: termios: not found
# termio
ksh: termio: not found
# pkg_add libc6-dev
quirks-2.304 signed on 2017-04-02T15:01:33Z
Can't find libc6-dev
# pkg_add libc6     
quirks-2.304 signed on 2017-04-02T15:01:33Z
Can't find libc6
#
```

What can I do about it? The code compiles with Ubuntu 1604.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<termio.h>` header is not standard, even though it is available on Linux.  The standard header is POSIX [`<termios.h>`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/termios.h.html).

On my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS VM image, the file contains, in its entirety:

```
/* Compatible <termio.h> for old `struct termio' ioctl interface.
   This is obsolete; use the POSIX.1 `struct termios' interface
   defined in <termios.h> instead.  */

#include <termios.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
```

If you use non-standard headers, you can expect not to find them on other systems.  You can create yourself a copy of `<termio.h>` using the information above.  You may be lucky and find that the BSD `<sys/ioctl.h>` (it does exist) contains the information you need — if any — but it is not a header standardized by POSIX so all bets are off.  If you're only using standard symbols from `<termios.h>`, you should be safe.